# Plot Time series according to a request by the user in R

Tags: r, time, rodbc

I have a table like this - name - MyData

```
Employee_Number Symbol  Count_Jan Am_Jan Count_Feb Am_Feb ... CountAug AmAug 
2232             23       40        34       32       11           23    12
2131             32       11        13       32       42           12    90
```

about 3,000,000 records. 
I want to write a code that the user will enter Employee_Number and Symbol 
And this will plot for him a time serie of the data - t:wo graphs Count And amount in the same plot, diffrent colors from Jan To Aug.

Any tips how to this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Assuming that you also need a user interface, I would recommend Shiny - http://shiny.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thank's! but any help with writing the script?